# Best practices for socket.io connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I am building a facebook clone and I need socket.io for a chat feature.

1) Should I keep a connection as soon as the user logs in or 2) Should I make connection only when the user opens a chat and close the connection when the chat is closed?

In the future, I may want to add a feature outside of chat (such as the page refreshing when someone posts a picture), which would require the server -> client communication.

Is 1) or 2) the best practice for my use case?

Comment: Do you not want the user to be notified of new messages while the chat is closed?

Comment: Yes. However, I am worried that theres going to be a lot of overhead in constantly maintaining a socket connection.

Comment: Facebook seems to keep its chatting websocket open constantly.

Comment: Could you provide any references or supporting evidence for that?

Comment: If you look in the network tab in devtools when on facebook, you can filter for ws and see the lone chat websocket connection. Also, the fact that you will always receive new chat messages, even if you don't have the chat open.